# nginx ssl redirect

Tags: nginx, ssl

I have SSL-sertificate for **www.** mydomain.com
How is the right config for nginx to get desired:

- SSL request without **www** (https://mydomain.com/somefile) will be redirected to https://**www.** mydomain.com/somefile

This doesn't work, broser shows SSL-warning (wrong domain) :(

> ```
> server
> {
>         listen  443 ssl;
>         server_name mydomain.com;
>         rewrite ^(.*) https://www.mydomain.com$1 permanent;
>         ssl_certificate      intermediate.crt;
>         ssl_certificate_key  www.mydomain.com.key;
> }
> ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since ssl handshake and certificate check occurs before any HTTP communication there is no way to make redirect without browser's warning.

Comment: Apart from getting another certificate for the second domain.